# How to convert setup.vdproj to .NET5

Tags: visual-studio, .net-5, vdproj

I have few other applications which I have converted to .NET5 and want to convert `.vdproj` to .NET5 as well.

But I don't know how it can be converted.

The same application `.vdproj` works in .NET framework.

I have converted other WPF and WCF to .NET5 and want to convert `.vdproj` now.

Comment: What exactly do you want to convert? `.vdproj` is used to build installers, so itself has no need to upgrade to the SDK style project format.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple answer: you cannot convert Visual Studio vdproj to .NET 5 because this project template only supports creating installer for .NET Framework projects, not for .NET Core projects.

To create MSI installer for .NET Core projects, there are other alternatives.
The most popular and free is using WiX. WiX is also used by .NET Core team to create installer for .NET Core SDK.

For more info, please visit WiX at: https://wixtoolset.org/

WiX supports Visual Studio 2015, 2017, 2019.
Besides WiX, you could also use paid tools such as InstallShield and AdvancedInstaller for VS 2017 and VS 2019.

**UPDATE 1:**

Thanks to comment from LexLi, the latest release of Deployment project extension tool for VS 2019 (version 1.0.0) support .NET Core 3.0 or later project.
My initial answer still stand: it reflects my experiences the last time I used Deployment Project in early 2020 around February 2020, at that time it didn't support .NET Core projects at all.

Still, the best option for now is to use WiX or the other paid alternatives such as InstallShield or AdvancedInstaller. Especially we have seen WiX being used by .NET Core team to create MSI installer of .NET Core SDK.

Comment: "this project template only supports creating installer for .NET Framework projects, not for .NET Core projects" is not quite accurate. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects It has been updated to support .NET Core.

Comment: @LexLi You're right! The support for .NET Core is available only for VS 2019. I'll update my answer then.

Comment: @LexLi,  please correct me if I am wrong. I can use the same `.vdproj` in my .NET core. No need of `WIX`.

Comment: @EriawanKusumawardhono, Do I need to use WIX to create MSI installer or I can use my existing `.vdproj`.

Comment: @LearningTech to be safe and flexible in the future, I suggest to use WiX at least v3.11 instead.